# Access dynamic object: javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, loops

I have written some code where in a loop, a function is called which passes the current object in that loop iteration to the function.

The problem is I don't know how to use the object because its dynamic and I can only access the obj parameter.

**Javascript**

```
objectifyTableRow(val, i); // Populate object with properties and values
```

**Val is an object which is passed to function objectifyTableRow**

```
function objectifyTableRow(objRow, count) { // Create objects for calculations

    var ii = 0;
    $('#ctl00_PageContent_freight_rate_column_chaair_r' + count + " " + 'td').each(function(i, val) { // begin each
        /* Concatenate column name with subcolumn name. example objFobCost.China/Sea Origin,Air */
        if (i < 3) { // columns 0,1,2 in table row
            if (ii < arraySubColumn.length) { // Air, Sea/air, sea subcolumns
                var PropertyName = arrayColumns[0] + arraySubColumn[ii];


                objRow[PropertyName] = parseFloat($(val).html()); // Set key name with var PropertyName 

                ii += 1;
            }

            if (ii == 3) { // Reset counter
                ii = 0;
            }
        } // end of outer if

        else if (i > 2 & i < 6) {
            if (ii < arraySubColumn.length) { // Air, Sea/air, sea subcolumns
                var PropertyName = arrayColumns[1] + arraySubColumn[ii];

                objRow[PropertyName] = parseFloat($(val).html());

                ii += 1;
            }

            if (ii == 3) { // Reset counter
                ii = 0;
            }
        } // end of outer if

        else if (i > 5 & i < 9) {
            if (ii < arraySubColumn.length) { // Air, Sea/air, sea subcolumns
                var PropertyName = arrayColumns[2] + arraySubColumn[ii];

                objRow[PropertyName] = parseFloat($(val).html());

                ii += 1;
            }

            if (ii == 3) { // Reset counter
                ii = 0;
            }
        } // end of outer if

        else if (i > 8 & i < 12) {
            if (ii < arraySubColumn.length) { // Air, Sea/air, sea subcolumns
                var PropertyName = arrayColumns[3] + arraySubColumn[ii];

                ii += 1;
            }

            if (ii == 3) { // Reset counter
                ii = 0;
            }
        } // end of outer if

        else {
            if (ii < arraySubColumn.length) { // Air, Sea/air, sea subcolumns
                var PropertyName = arrayColumns[4] + arraySubColumn[ii];

                           ii += 1;
            }

            if (ii == 3) { // Reset counter
                ii = 0;
            }
        } // end of else
    });                  // end of each loop TD
    beginCalc(objRow);
};
```

**Each object is passed to beginCalc so calculation can be made based on ID, Key and value**

```
function beginCalc(obj) {
    // Every obj used is passed to here
    $.each(obj, function(key, element) {
    alert('ID: ' + obj[this.id] + '\n' + 'key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + element); // Check correct obj id, key and value
});
```

The reason I am doing this is because the objects are storing values from an asp.net grid and I thought it would be cleaner to create objects for each grid row and then do the calculations in the code by selecing obj.key: value * obj.key: value. Rather than using getDocumentByElementId.

Any ideas how to programmatically access these objects by their ID in beginCalc function?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "object parameters"? You have the object keys and values, what parameters are you talking about?

Comment: When I call beginCalc() I supply an object as its arguement. Since this function call happens within a loop I am passing each object until the loop ends. so in beginCalc() I have multiple objects with different IDs. Each obj also has its own key and value pairing. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I understand that, but what are you looking for? You want an array of all the objects that you are passing to be available within `beginCalc()`? In that case you'll need to create that full array first, save it as a variable, and then iterate over that... there's no way to magically get a list of objects that hasn't been created yet. Maybe I'm still misunderstanding.

Comment: I want to know how to programmatically access the objects by ID. An array of all the objects could help.

Comment: If they all have a specific ID you want to end up with an object mapping those IDs to their corresponding objects. So yes, iterate through your original "object of objects" and build a new one assigning the ID as the key for each. Perhaps a library like [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#) would help keep some of your data structures organized.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a connection between DOM nodes and values. Try this approach (pseudocode):

```
var nodes = $(...select all the nodes...);
nodes.each( function( index, node ) {
    var obj = { node: node };
    beginCalc(obj);
} );
```

In `beginCalc()`, you can now access the DOM node with `obj.node`. You can use the same approach to put more data into the objects to keep everything in a single place (the DOM node that you need to update + all the data that you need to update it).

Comment: When you say "$(...select all the nodes...); "  I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean `$('#ctl00_PageContent_freight_rate_column_chaair_r' + count + " " + 'td')`. The main point is that you should create one `obj` for each node instead of saving the all node values under `PropertyName` in one object.